# SystemWebView on Android doesn't scroll

Tags: android, cordova

So I have my activity (extending CordovaActivity) on Android, which loads the content, but I am unable to scroll.

I already tried to add this code into my activity:

> ```
>     // Display vertical scrollbar and hide horizontal scrollBar
>     super.appView.getView().setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
>     super.appView.getView().setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
>     // set scrollbar style
>     super.appView.getView().setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
> ```

but didn't help.

Does anyone has an experience / solution to How can I make my Cordova WebView scrollable?